# How to split a media file

Tags: c#, video, media

i'm a new here, i'm doing an application that I can split a media file by giving a start position and an end position. How can i do that? I use c# language.
my english is not good, sorry.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ffmpeg via a shell process.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath.FullName;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "some ffmpeg commands here";
try {
    p.Start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ' trap error
}

String out = p.StandardError;
```